# В какой ситуации font-weight bolder будет менее жирный, чем bold?

Tags: css, css3

В какой ситуации font-weight bolder будет менее жирный, чем bold?

Comment: Я прошу прощения, а зачем делать, чтобы "самый жирный" стал худее "жирного"? Так или иначе, это, на мой взгляд, должно определяться самим шрифтом.

Comment: В случае бага в браузере?

Comment: @VladD, вы не правы. Шрифт может поддерживать до 9-ти уровней font-weight (100, 200, 300, ..., 900), при этом 'bold' соответствует значению 700. 'bolder' интерпретируется по следующим правилам https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Meaning_of_relative_weights , в зависимости от унаследованного от родителя значения font-weight.

Comment: @dzhioev: Не знал, спасибо! То есть, bolder имеет законное право быть светлее, чем bold? o_O

Comment: @VladD, на да. Лишь бы "bolder then parent".

Comment: @dzhioev: Ыыыыы!

Answer (score 2):

```css
div div[style]:after { content: " (" attr(style) ")" }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&amp;subset=latin" media="all">

<div style="font-weight:lighter">
  <div>1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:normal">1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:bolder">1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:bold">1234567890</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div style="font-weight:lighter; font-family:Roboto">
  <div>1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:normal">1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:bolder">1234567890</div>
  <div style="font-weight:bold">1234567890</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример со шрифтом с поддержкой font-weight, тоньше чем normal https://jsfiddle.net/69cn24uz/ .

Comment: @dzhioev, да, так лучше смотрится :) В этом и была идея, что относительное изменение ведёт себя несколько иначе, чем абсолютное.

Comment: @dzhioev, добавил в ответ пример с тем шрифтом.

Comment: это типа болдер лихтера и никакой связи с болдом?

Comment: @Grundy, ну был себе normal у body. Его сделали тоньше внешним div'ом. А потом пришёл bolder и вернул всё как было. А bold всё это время стоял в сторонке потому что он - константа :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, я так и сказал :-D